# Opening a link in the same page

Tags: html

I have put a link in an HTML document. How can I open the linked document (`link1.html`) under the link **within the same page**?

**`links.html`:**

```
<body>
    <h3>Links</h3>
    <a href="link1.html">link1</a> 
</body>
```

output like:

Links
  [link1]

---

### content of link1.html

Comment: It does seem correct. Are you sure the link1.html is in the same directory as links.html?

Comment: This is not trivial - the only way to do this without JavaScript is by using an iframe element. Can you use that? It would have to be in the desired position, and already occupy space.

Comment: You're new to HTML aren't you?

Comment: @Thew read the question closely. `under the link within the same page`

Comment: Check out the "Alt 3" of this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152976/clicking-a-link-display-it-in-different-div-on-same-page#answer-8153230

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='link1.html' target='myIframe'>link1</a><br />
<iframe name='myIframe'></iframe>
```

If you want it to be less crappy, I suggest you use JavaScript.

Comment: how to use javascript for this

Comment: Using AJAX, you can find tons of information about AJAX on the internet.

Comment: i used ur code . it shows the content of link1.html without clicking the link?????

Answer (score 1):

<sup>As has been sayed in the comments:</sup>
Probably what you want is an `<iframe>`. It can be used to **embed** a web page into an HTML document. You can see more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iframe). Below is an example.

**In your case:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Links</h1>
    <a href="link1.html">link1</a>

    <h2>Contents of link1</h2>
    <iframe src="link1.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
</body>
```

**Update:** To show the IFrame when the link's clicked, you can use this code instead:

```
<body>
    <h1>Links</h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contents1').style.cssText = ''">link1</a>

    <div id="contents1" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Contents of link1</h2>
        <iframe src="link1.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ur code showing the content of link1.html without clicking on the link

Comment: @ayman **Here's when the JavaScript comes up!** I will edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: @ayman when you have found a _good answer_ for your question, please **accept** it. It's easy, just click the **tick** below the votes area on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the property tag "Target" which is used to specify, where  the  document to  be opened, means new window or same page or new tab..
eg:
Click Here

There are six values of the target tag like parent,blank and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you'll have to do this using some kind of javascript Ajax call to load the other page under the link. Another technique could be to include in your link1.html the same header as in links.html, but you're going into copy/paste spaghettiness...

Comment: @ayman If you're using JQuery for example, the ajax call can be like the following snippet (with an element with markup id "result" in your html) `code` $.ajax({url:'links1.html', success: function(data){$('#result').html(data);}});