# Clicking a link display it in Different Div on Same Page

Tags: php, javascript, css

I would like to know if there is a way to be able to click a Link on the navigational Div tag and have it display on the content Div like if i had

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="infoto (div id="content")">a link </a></div>
<div id="content>show the stuff</div>
```

From the comments below - the OP stated the following :

I am trying to redo a website but my imagagination is getting the better of me. If I have three links like home, about author, and about our mission. I would like to be able to click about author and in the main_content div tag show the html file aboutauthor.html

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, did you want the link to show a hidden div? or have the link append something to the div? or something else?

Comment: I think, you need to work with AJAX.

Comment: Sounds like you're ready to jump into the wonderful world of javascript.  Try reading up on it a bit, and post some of the things you've tried.  This page is probably a good start and gets you half-way to your answer:  [http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/javascript/js101/](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/javascript/js101/)

Comment: @dev - no, he doesn't need ajax.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5NEu3/2/

Comment: I am trying to redo a website but my imagagination is getting the better of me. If I have three links like home, about author, and about our mission. I would like to be able to click about author and in the main_content div tag show the html file aboutauthor.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Alt 1: Use jquery tabs:**
See demo and code here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

**Alt 2: Hide/show div in same html file:**

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#content1">Show content 1</a>
    <a href="#content2">Show content 2</a>
    <a href="#content3">Show content 3</a>
</div>

<div id="content1" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the stuff1</div> 
<div id="content2" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the stuff2</div>
<div id="content3" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the stuff3</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#nav a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".toggle").hide();
    var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
    $(toShow).show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5NEu3/3/

**Alt 3: Load from server ondemand:**

To load html into your main div you should use: http://api.jquery.com/load/
Follow examples on that site. And be aware that the html side you are loading must be in same domain as you are hosting the new page.

Html

```
<a href="http:www.test.com/test1.html">Show content 1</a>
<a href="http:www.test.com/test2.html">Show content 2</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#nav a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#maindiv').load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: This answer is very similar to mine, but probably more suitable for your application. You said you only wanted 3 sections(home, about, author) and these should not really need seperate HTML files for each. It would probably be better (and faster) to include them all on the one site, and just hide the ones not in use as IntoTheVoid has provided example of.

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep on your last night, I am in Japan time zone so forgive me about that I have not tried it but I have 8 sections and would like to do this every time.

Comment: See my new alt 1 above, jquery ui may help you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you could do something like this.

This will open the site `<a href="example.html">` and put it inside of the `<div id="content">` when you click it, and then disable changing the whole site.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
 });
</script>

<div id="nav">
   <a href="somepage.html">Some page</a>
   <a href="someotherpage.html">Some other page</a>
   <a href="smypage.html">My page</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
 show the stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function setContent(div, content)
{
    getElementById(div).innerHtml = content;
    return false; // return false to ignore the click
}

<a href="path-to-non-js-browsers-and-search-engines.html" onClick="setContent('content','foo');">a link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

to show a hidden div (i think this is what you wanted)

the javascript (using jQuery)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showdiv").click(function () {
       $("#hiddendiv").show();             
    });
  });
 <script>
```

the html

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="showdiv">Show the Div</a>
<div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none;">Content here</div>
```

you can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GordnFreeman/AevSq/2/)