# Click link in DIV and show PHP/HTML in separate DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that changes and I want to show content in the DIV id="main_content" based on the link associated with the item selected in DIV class="items"

Here is the jQuery code I am using (*edited*)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".items a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#main_content").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});

</script>
```

This code seems logically correct and I have searched extensively before posting here.  This question/post was one of the most helpful in constructing the code: [Clicking a link display it in Different Div on Same Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152976/clicking-a-link-display-it-in-different-div-on-same-page)

When the link is clicked it opens in a new tab.  So my question is, why isn't this working?

I am open to other suggestions besides jQuery.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

OK, so after some trial and error I found that another script was causing the problem.  I have the script below in use to make the entire DIV a clickable link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".items").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
  })
 });
</script>
```

Is there anyway I can use both scripts together?

Comment: So what's the issue? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried debugging with the console?

Comment: Please show your HTML. If your `href` points to a different site, you won't be able to `.load()` it; you'll need an iframe instead.

Comment: Sorry... my question is, why isn't this working?  I will edit to include the question.

Comment: @mblase75, the page is part of the same site and within the same directory folder

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console in the developer tools ?

Comment: I do not see any errors.

Comment: OK, so I removed the e.stopPropagation(); and tested it on a live server and I am making some progress.  However, once the content is loaded into the DIV, it then tries to load another undefined link in a separate tab.

I think part of my initial problem was trying to test/develop the site on my local machine.  Although jQuery appears to be working in some instances, it is not working with this one.

Comment: Is there any way to use both scripts above together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that code seems right( without looking at the markup). On a side note you could just `return false;` if you would like to both prevent the default action and stop the event from propagating. I would suggest you only `e.preventDefault()` unless you need to really also stop the event from propagating.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the HTML I am using.  Thanks for the tip