# How can I make entire DIV clickable AND open child links in separate DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I asked a precursor to this question here:
[Click link in DIV and show PHP/HTML in separate DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878458/click-link-in-div-and-show-php-html-in-separate-div)

Then, after I removed the first script shown below, I was able to get the second script to work.  I revised my question, but it appears to have gone silent.  So I have a slightly modified question.

What is the conflict between the 2 scripts below and how can I modify them to work in tandem?  Basically I want to be able to click anywhere in the DIV (".side_items") and have the child anchor links open in a separate DIV ("#main_content")

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".side_items").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
  })
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".side_items a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
       $("#main_content").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});

</script>
```

HTML: (slightly simplified)

```
<div id="main_content">
</div>

<div id="right_side">
  <div class="side_items">
  <a href="content.html">
  <img src="images/examplethumb.png" /><br />
  Content</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both scripts work independently to achieve their individual desired result.

Comment: reposting questions is not what you are supposed to do, there are lots of ways to bump your question to receive attention again, like for example, editing it.

Comment: I apologize.  I have been very actively trying to learn the appropriate use of SO, however I am still a n00b.  I did edit my previous question and my question is not exactly the same.  I figured this would be a simpler and less confusing way to ask.

Comment: Although asking this slightly modified question again may not have been proper, it effectively solved my problem within 20 minutes.  Where my previous (edited) question has been quite for over 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".side_items").click(function(){ 
        $("#main_content").load($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
        return false; 
    }) 
});
```

Breaking it down:

```
$(".side_items").click(fn);
```

Find all the elements with a class of `side_items` and assign a click event handler (`fn`) to them.  Each time one of these elements is clicked, `fn` is executed with the context of the element.  In the discarded code you were using the selector `.side_items a`, which meant the click handler was only bound to the links inside the div, not the div itself.

```
$(this).find("a").attr("href")
```

Find all the links that are contained within the current element (`this`), and get the value of the `href` attribute from the first element found.  In the discarded code the context (`this`) was a link.  Since our handler is now bound to the containing div, the context is also the div.  To get the link you have to find it.

```
$("#main_content").load(href);
```

Find the element with an id of `main_content` and load the content found at `href` into it.  In the discarded code you were setting `location.href`, which causes the page to navigate away.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're trying to assign the $().ready(..) handler twice.

Try combing scripts like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var change_location = function(){ 
    $(".side_items").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
        return false;
    });
}

var load_location = function(){
    $(".side_items a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#main_content").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
}

$().ready(function(){
    change_location();
    load_function();
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I am still learning javascript and jQuery.