# Link not opening in DIV using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to click a link in one div and have it open an HTML document in another div (named infoblock) that sits beside the original div. I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951164/how-can-i-make-entire-div-clickable-and-open-child-links-in-separate-div?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I can't get it to work. I found a couple other variations on the net, but still no luck. Part of the link needs to transmit a variable so I'm not sure if that's part of the problem. I tried attaching the click function to a div surrounding the link with an ID of "nav" as well as the link itself with an ID of "details". When I click on the link, it opens the correct page in the full window, not in the div it's supposed to go to. Thank you in advance for any help.

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#reservename").click(function() {
        $("#infoblock").load("createhandle.html");
      });
      $("#uploadpic").click(function() {
        $("#infoblock").load("uploadpic.php");
      });
      $("#deletechar").click(function() {
        $("#infoblock").load("selectdelete.php");
      });
      $("#nav").click(function() {
        $("#infoblock").load($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
        return false;
      })
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="charlist" class="block">
    <b>Your Characters:<b>
    <br>
    <button id="reservename">Reserve A Name</button>
    <button id="uploadpic">Upload A Picture</button>
    <button id="deletechar">Delete</button>
    <?php 
        $result5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM handle WHERE user='$handle' ORDER BY charname ASC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
        {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan=5 align=left><img src='../pictures/" . $row['face'] . "' border=3></td>";
        echo "<th align=left><a href='chat.php?charname=" . $row['charname'] . "'>" . $row['charname'] . "</a></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th align=left><a href='choosepic.php?charname=" . $row['charname'] . "'>Choose Picture</a></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th align=left><div id='nav'><a id='details' href='../details.html?charname=" . $row['charname'] . "'>Details</a></div></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        if ($row['type'] == 'new'){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th align=left><a href='createsheet.php?charname=" . $row['charname'] . "'>Create</a></th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
</div>
<p id="infoblock" class="block"></p>
```

Comment: Your link's id is #details and none of your events is programmed against that id.

Comment: You probably need to add the full URL instead of just file name inside load function.

Comment: I tried programming for the link's id of #details and the surrounding div's ID of #nav, neither worked. The example I posted was for the #nav attempt, but the #details one was the same with details in place of nav.

Comment: I just tried adding the full URL and it didn't work. I was hoping it would be something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the default behaviour when anchor tag is clicked In order to do that that you have to be listen for click on the anchor itself not div and `return false` in order to prevent its default behaviour. So your code will become like this

```
  $('#details').click(function(e){
     {
       e.preventDefault(); //instead of this you can also return false
       $("#infoblock").load($('#details').attr("href"));
     }
   });
```

Comment: No luck, does the same thing and opens in the full window and not the div. But thank you for trying.

Comment: plz post the full source code here so I can better look whats going wrong

Comment: I updated my original post to show all of the php/html code. I already posted all the javascript I had.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#details').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#infoblock").html('<object type="text/html" data="'+$('#details').attr("href")+'" >');    
     });
  });
```

Comment: Didn't work, still opens in the full window instead of the div. But thank you!