# Issue with showing div when I click on link

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm having an issue with showing a div after clicking a link.

When I press one of the links I have in the first div a new div would appear underneath.

I've been testing this in jsfiddle, everything seems to be working fine there, but when I put it in the map page, nothing happens when I click on the link...

Here is the working jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5NEu3/132/

Here is the original map page in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/F2arQ/

Here is the original page that I'm testing this on, it's the region with the dot saying "test":
http://iseeit.no/webtest/

Also the link to the answer that helped me figure out the jquery code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153230/1238117

Why is this happening?
What am I doing wrong?
Is there something preventing it from working in the original jquery files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // and this line
 $("#hedmarkvalg a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".toggle").hide();
   var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
   $(toShow).show();
   });
 }); // and close it
```

You forgot to add `$(document).ready()` at the beginning of your code. You can check out more info about it at [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) site

Comment: Haha!, I've been at this for 4 hours straight, could seriously not figure this out at all, and then you come in here with you awesomeness, and figure it out in a minute. Thanks! love you right now!

Comment: Also regarding the fade it and out? Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: You should try changing `$(toShow).show();` to `$(toShow).fadeToggle();`

Comment: I tried it and it worked, I also want it to fadeout when I press the same link, so I tried this:  `$(toShow).fadeIn("slow");` `$(toShow).fadeOut("slow");` now it fades in and out automatically in just a second, what am I doing wrong?